# Is it possible to post a message to a facebook wall purely with html?

Tags: html, facebook

A client has asked if it is possible to include a link that posts a message to your facebook wall through a html newsletter. This usually happens through an iframe but is it possible to copy the link and use it as an `<a>` tag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for the facebook sharer link?

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=URL_TO_SHARE
```

Where `URL_TO_SHARE` is replaced by the web address you want to share on facebook for example `www.google.com`

HTML

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Click Here To Share</a>
```